# What is the difference between getters and setters? I mean, is it a mistake if I use them interchangeably?

Tags: javascript, object, getter, setter

For example at w3school.com there was this piece of code:

```
// Define object
var obj = {counter : 0};

// Define setters
Object.defineProperty(obj, "reset", {
  get : function () {this.counter = 0;}
});
Object.defineProperty(obj, "increment", {
  get : function () {this.counter++;}
});
Object.defineProperty(obj, "decrement", {
  get : function () {this.counter--;}
});
Object.defineProperty(obj, "add", {
  set : function (value) {this.counter += value;}
});
Object.defineProperty(obj, "subtract", {
  set : function (value) {this.counter -= value;}
});

// Play with the counter:
obj.reset;
obj.add = 5;
obj.subtract = 1;
obj.increment;
obj.decrement;
```

They used getters. I replaced getters by setters and ran the same code, and it ran exactly the same. So I have two questions:

1. Why would they use here "get"?
2. Is there a traditionally accepted way (conventional) in using getters and setters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the same, getter is called if you access a property `foo.bar`, setter is called if you set a property `foo.bar='baz'` using `=` operator.

```js
// Define object
var obj = {counter : 0};

// Define setters
Object.defineProperty(obj, "reset", {
  get : function () {console.log('get')},
  set : function (value) {console.log('set')}
});

// Play with the counter:
obj.reset;// "get"
obj.reset=2;// "set"
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can misuse getters to do the work of a setter but you should stick to the convention of:

1. `set` activated when you use the assignment operator `=`. The value
   on the right side of the assignment operator will be passed to the
   setter as an argument, the value of that parameter should be assigned somewhere.
2. `get` activated when you request a value, a value should always be returned even it is `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you very much. You made it clear to me now. Apparently I cannot put "accept answer" to two people :(

Comment: You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept an answer, at any time. An answer must be un-accepted before a new answer can be accepted.